How To Apply Label To InlineShapes Pictures Via MS Word VBA
I'd like to apply a label on the bottom of a picture using MS Word VBA.
Private Sub btnLoopShapes_Click()
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'loop through inline shapes
    For i = 1 To Shapes.Count
        'check if the current shape is an picture
        If Shapes.Item(i).Type = msoPicture Then
            'check the border color to black
            'Shapes.Item(i).Line.BackColor = vbBlack
            'create the border with to 20
            'Shapes.Item(i).Line.Weight = 20
            'change the border style to single
            'Shapes.Item(i).Line.Style = msoLineSingle
            
            Shapes.Item(i).Title = "Exemplo de Título"
            MsgBox "Title: " & Shapes.Item(i).Title
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

According to PeterT:
    Private Sub btnRename_Click()
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'loop through inline shapes
    For i = 1 To DocTeste.InlineShapes.Count
        'check if the current shape is an picture
        If DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).Select
            
            '1st TRY
            'Selection.InsertCaption "Foto " & i
            
            '2nd TRY
            'Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Foto " & i, _
                Title:="Exemplo de Foto", _
                Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
            
            '3rd TRY
            'Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            'Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _
                Title:=": Sales Results", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
            
            'Last TRY
            DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).AlternativeText = "Foto " & (i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

According to John Korchok:
Private Sub btnShow2_Click()
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objShape As Object
    
    'loop through inline shapes
    For i = 1 To DocTeste.InlineShapes.Count
        'check if the current shape is an picture
        If DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).Select
            DocTeste.Range.InsertAfter vbNewLine & DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).Title & vbNewLine & DocTeste.InlineShapes.Item(i).AlternativeText
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

with this code I can change the backcolor, weight, style... I can even change the title. but there's nothing about changing the label.
I need to show a small description of the picture on the bottom, which I can't with the title.
I'd appreciate your help.

Shapes and InlineShapes are different.  MS doc:

Document.InlineShapes property (Word)


Document.Shapes property (Word)


Try looking at the InsertCaption method to set the "label" of an image. Also look at CaptionLabel method

Selection.InlineShapes(1).AlternativeText = "Exemplo de Título" may also work for you.

@PeterT I've tried using the code that you suggested me but, it did not work. I'm using VBA for Word 365. on the top, I've put the code exactly how I'm doing.

@JohnKorchok your code works fine. I can add an alternative text to the InLineShape. now, I need to find a way to place this alternative text right on the bottom of the shape. the code that I've pasted on the top is the nearest that I reached, so far.
